# mvc 3 update model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a view that displays several checkbox lists of items in tables (the lists are dynamic).  I need to know how to update the ViewModel when the user clicks on a checkbox so that when control returns to the controller it can inspect the viewmodel to determine which items were selected.

The VM contains several properties such as

```
public IEnumerable<IFilterItem> Cities;

public Interface IFilterItem
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

What I need help with is how to set the view's copy of the model data in the checkbox's onclick handler.  Thanks as always, you guys are great!

Comment: OK I've read a bit more on this and it appears that I may have to write a custom binder or do it manually in javascript as the default binder tries to match names in the posted data with property names on the viewmodel. Since my list is being supplied via a property of a property (Model.Filters.Cities, etc) I think the default binder can't resolve it.  Can we close this question and I will post another if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the CheckBoxFor helper? If so, when control returns to the controller your view model should just have IsSelected set based on the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Actually I'm using ajax/jquery to update the view but I did try your suggestion and the model did not get updated.

Comment: OK I've read a bit more on this and it appears that I may have to write a custom binder or do it manually in javascript as the default binder tries to match names in the posted data with property names on the viewmodel. Since my list is being supplied as a property of a property I think the default binder can't resolve it.